# Navbar is not displayed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style.css';



const NavBar = ({ history }) => {
   return (
     <nav>
        <NavLink className="home-link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/about">About</NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/search">Search</NavLink>
        <button>Back</button>
    </nav>
 );
}

export default NavBar;
```

and this is the app component:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 import { NavBar, SearchForm } from './components';
 import { Welcome, Search ,About} from './pages'
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react- 
router-dom';

const PageNotFound = () => (
   <div> 404</div>
)

// function App() {
  class App extends Component {
     render () {
   return (

     <div id="app">
        <header>
        <NavBar />
        </header>
         <main>
             <Switch>
                <Route  exact path="/" component={Welcome}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/search" component={Search} />

            </Switch> 
             <SearchForm/>
        </main>
    </div>
   )
}
}

export default App;
```

when I npm start my application, it does not show the the navbar, I am missing something? I've imported the navbar component into my App.js file, and ive tried following tutorials online but to no avail.

the index.js file in my component file

```
export { default as NavBar } from './NavBar';
export { default as SearchForm } from './SearchForm';
export { default as Result } from './Result';
```

Comment: check your CSS and elements from the developer console "Elements" tab. You can just right-click and "inspect" HTML elements

Comment: What's your *components/index.js* file looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to define a layout.
It maybe looks as follows.

```js
MainLayout = ({children}) => {
   return (
    <div id="app">
        <header>
        <NavBar />
        </header>
         <main>
             {children}
             <SearchForm/>
        </main>
        </div>
   )
}
```

And just define the router like this

```js
<MainLayout>
    <Switch>...
</MainLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, it still does not work? - this is how I defined it

Comment: class App extends Component {
        render () {
    return (
    
        <div id="app">
           <header>
           <NavBar />
           </header>
            <main>
            <SearchForm/>
              
            </main>
            <mainLayout>
            <Switch>
                    <Route  exact path="/" component={Welcome}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
  
                </Switch> 
            </mainLayout>
        </div>
    )
}
}

Answer (score 0):

First you haven't used Router component to wrap your routes and you have imported them twice. Second please look into developer consoles for debugging.

Your App component should look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavBar, SearchForm } from "./components";
import { Welcome, Search, About } from "./pages";

const PageNotFound = () => <div> 404</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <Router>
          <header>
            <NavBar />
          </header>
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
            </Switch>
            <SearchForm />
          </main>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, this still does not work, and is displaying my index.html file instead.

Comment: Any errors on the developer console? Can you recreate it on codesandbox?

Comment: yes this is the error im getting Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserRouter is not defined
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at startup:4
    at startup:6

Comment: can you try replacing your App component with the one I provided?

Comment: yes I have done that, but im still getting a uncaught reference error

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-thunder-3bsie
This is the small demo I created based on your problem. It's working fine.

Are you sure you have installed all the required dependencies? Can you push your code to github and share the link? It'll help to debug more properly.

Comment: sure whats ur github username

Comment: tusharkhatiwada